# Определение наиболее эффективного решения нахождения общих элементов двух списков

Tags: python, python-3.x, список

Задача:

`a`, `b` - списки, отсортированные по возрастанию. Вернуть список `c`, содержащий только те элементы из `a`, которые есть в `b`. Решение должно быть вычислительно эффективным.

Кто знает, какие недостатки в решениях этой задачи? Кто может предложить более лучший и эффективный вариант решения этой задачи? Оптимальный по скорости вычисления. И как оценить вычислительную сложность данных решений?

Решения:

Вариант 1:

```
def get_intersection(a, b):
    a = set(a)
    b = set(b)
    c = sorted(list(a&b))
    return c
```

Вариант 2:

```
def get_list_difference(a, b):
    l = []
    for i in a:
        if i in b:
            l.append(i)
    return l
```

Comment: Должен ли результирующий список оставаться отсортированным? Если нет, то `sorted` излишне. Впрочем, результирующий `set` скорее всего и так уже будет отсортирован.

Comment: Насчёт сортированности `set` я наврал, не будет он сортирован.

Answer (score 2):

Разницу в производительности можно измерить например с помощью библиотеки **`timeit`**.

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> b = [3,5,7,8]
>>> 
>>> set(a) & set(b)
{3, 5}
>>> 
>>> import timeit
>>> 
>>> print(timeit.timeit('sorted(list(set([1,2,3,4,5]) & set([3,5,7,8])))', number=10000))
0.0662280490005287
>>> print(timeit.timeit('set([1,2,3,4,5]) & set([3,5,7,8])', number=10000))
0.04045701100039878
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

Оптимально будет использовать алгоритм двух указателей:

```
def get_intersection(a, b):
    c = []
    u = 0
    for i in range(len(a)):
        while u < len(b) and b[u] < a[i]:
            u += 1
        if u == len(b):
            break
        if a[i] == b[u]:
            c.append(a[i])
    return c

a = [0, 1, 1, 2, 5, 7, 10]
b = [-1, 1, 3, 7, 9, 12]
print(get_intersection(a, b))
# [1, 1, 7]
```

Этот алгоритм проходит по каждому элементу из двух массивов не более одного раза, поэтому должен быть побыстрее множеств. Сложность - O(len(a) + len(b)), то есть O(N).

Ваши решения имеют сложности O(NlogN) и O(N^2) соответственно. Первый использует сортировку, второй - по сути двойной цикл.

Comment: Ваш вариант выкинет ошибку, если последний элемент `a` больше последнего элемента `b`, например если `a = [2]`, `b = [1]`

Comment: @CrazyElf спасибо, исправил

Answer (score 0):

**По вычислительной сложности**

Основные параметры вычислительной сложности над различными типами массивов можно прочитать на питоновской Wiki в разделе [`TimeComplexity`](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity). Дальше комбинируете с тем, что у Вас в алгоритме реализуется и тем, что реализовано в сторонних функциях и классах.

По Вашему примеру. Если где ошибаюсь, то надеюсь коллеги поправят.

Вариант 1) Если преобразуем список (`list`) в множество (`set`), то стоимость операции `O(n)`. Далее пересечение `O(min(len(s), len(t))`, если равны, то `O(n)`, а потом снова в преобразуем список `O(n)`. И последнее сортировка списка `O(n log n)`. Итого в худшем случае `O(n) + O(n) + O(n) + O(n) + O(n) + O(n log n)`

Вариант 2) Первый цикл `O(n)`, попадание в список `O(n)`, `append()` со стоимостью одной операции `O(1)`. Где-то итого приблизительно будет `O(n^2) + O(n)`

Отсюда с ростом списка первый вариант будет эффективнее, а второй лучше себя проявит на очень малых списках. Еще такой момент, что в случае со множествами итог будет из уникальных значений, а в случае списка возможны повторения.

**Протестировать**

Протестировать все это можно с помощью `timeit` или библиотеки `timench`. Пример кода для второй в этом гисте по ссылке https://gist.github.com/ndrwpvlv/d011e129ffdb3816caad8dff74517e86. Там же внизу результаты для упорядоченных и случайных списков длиной три ячейки и тысяча. С ростом длины соответственно вариант с множествами дает меньше временных затрат.

По `timeit` примеры в соседнем посте.

**По оптимальному варианту**. На мой взгляд, если нужна сортировка, то чуть эффективнее будет

```
sorted(set(a).intersection(b))
```

Answer (score 0):

Если самому считать, то примерно такой алгоритм получится. Но слишком много проверок на выход за пределы массивов приходится делать. Измерения показывают, что через `set` быстрее считается. С другой стороны, если числа в списках могут повторяться, то `set` не справится с задачей.

```
def get_intersect(a, b):
    c = []
    ia = ib = 0
    if not a or not b:
        return c
    while True:
        if a[ia] == b[ib]:
            c.append(a[ia])
            ia += 1
            ib += 1
            if ia >= len(a) or ib >= len(b):
                return c
        while a[ia] < b[ib]:
            ia += 1
            if ia >= len(a):
                return c
        while a[ia] > b[ib]:
            ib += 1
            if ib >= len(b):
                return c
```